# How can run JMeter with limited CSV login details for multiple threads ?

Tags: jmeter

Im just trying to run my JMeter script for 20 threads. I'm use CSV data set config for read login data. I set there are only 5 login details in CSV file. When i run the script only first 5 request got pass and rest of the thread request got fail. Anyone can suggest a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following configuration to your [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config):

- Recycle on EOF - `True`
- Stop thread on EOF - `False`

[image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config - loop image 1]

When JMeter reaches the end of the CSV file it will start over so 6th thread will get `<EOF>` as the value, 7th thread will pick 1st line, 8th thread will pick 2nd line, etc.

You can put your login request under the [IF Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and use the following condition:

`"${line}" != "<EOF>"`

to avoid the login failure due to this `<EOF>` variable value.

[image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config loop file without error]